# Remove comma from print output

Tags: regex, perl

Substitution in grep produces an extra comma in the output.

```
open(READ,"<","C:/Users/lab/voice_port.txt");
my @file=<READ>;
close(READ);

my @device_name=grep(s/^(\S+)#.*\n$/$1/,@file);
my @port_number=grep(s/Foreign Exchange Station\s(\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/?\d{0,2})\s.*\n$/$1/,@file);
my @port_status=grep(s/.*Administrative State is\s(\S+).*\n$/$1/,@file);
my @number, @device_type=grep(s/.*Station-id name\s(.*)\sStation-id number\s(\+\d+)\n$/$2,$1/,@file);
```

Printing the values:

```
for my $x(0..$#port_number)
{
print $device_name[0].",".$port_number[$x].",".$port_status[$x].",".$number[$x].",".$device_type[$x]."\n";
}
```

Result:

```
Router1,0/1/1,UP,,+3255413655555,MKD, Reproc
Router1,0/1/2,DOWN,,+3289791148755632,Fax Unbek.
Router1,0/1/3,UP,,+3217825478220844,Kitfax Ler
```

If comma is removed between port status and number in the "for" cycle, it looks as expected (without extra comma). Is there a way to remove this extra comma in the grep function?

Expected result:

```
Router1,0/1/1,UP,+3255413655555,MKD, Reproc
Router1,0/1/2,DOWN,+3289791148755632,Fax Unbek.
Router1,0/1/3,UP,+3217825478220844,Kitfax Ler
```

Input file:

```
#
#
Router1# show voice port 
Foreign Exchange Station 0/1/1 Slot is 1, Sub-unit is 1, Port is 1
Operation State is DORMANT
Administrative State is UP
Station-id name MKD, Reproc Station-id number +3255413655555
Digit Duration Timing is set to 100 ms
.
.
```

Comment: You should provide a sample of voice_port.txt file.

Comment: (1) The code misuses `grep` (2) In the last line `@number` takes all elements /// But you need to improve the question: what is your input and what output do you expect?

Comment: question updated. also tried with space to separate the group references (/$2 $1/) but extra comma remained

Comment: @number does not get assigned, don't you see?

Comment: Thank you, but this is still just too hard to figure out. Do you have repeated sections starting with `Router1` line, always with same following lines (on which successive `grep`s are supposed to apply)? For one, the first `s/^(\S+)` will match all consecutive non-space characters (up to the last `#`) _on each line_, and not only "device" (`Router1` I presume). Can you explain your processing?

Comment: got it. i see where the issue was. thank you all for the assistance.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
my @number, @device_type
  =grep(s/.*Station-id name\s(.*)\sStation-id number\s(\+\d+)\n$/$2,$1/,@file);
```

...should be changed into two greps since you cannot set both arrays at once like you tried:

```
my@number =grep(s/.*Station-id name\s(.*)\sStation-id number\s(\+\d+)\n$/$2/,@file);
my@devtype=grep(s/.*Station-id name\s(.*)\sStation-id number\s(\+\d+)\n$/$1/,@file);
```